# Python: handle python list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list `x = [['a',1], ['b',3],['d',5]]` and I want to store the values of the second column in a new list `y = [['a',1], ['b',3], ['c',0], ['d',5]]`
Not necessarily the first list would have all a,b,c,d entries.
Here is what I have right now:

```
    x = [['a',1], ['b',3],['d',5]]
    y = []
    b = ('a','b','c','d')
    for key in b:
        for i, sublist in enumerate(x):
            if sublist[0] == key:
                y.append(sublist)
            else
                y.append([key,0])
    print y
```

This gives:

```
[['a', 1], ['a', 0], ['a', 0], ['b', 0], ['b', 3], ['b', 0], ['c', 0], ['c', 0], ['c', 0], ['d', 0], ['d', 0], ['d', 5]]
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you ultimately just trying to make sure that the key in list x is in list b? Because if that is the case, you don't need to nest loops like that. Which in turn means you should make use of the `in` keyword instead. Furthermore, I'm not sure what your goal is when finding a match. Are you looking to always update with the latest value?

Comment: Each time in the for loop you are checking for the condition and appending to the list.That's so long result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first approach (somewhat similar to what you intended to write), we can use explicit looping:

```
x = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['d', 5]]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
y = []

for key in b:
  for k, v in x:
    if key == k:       # if the key was found
      y.append([k, v]) # add it with its value
      break            # and break from the loop
  else:
    y.append([key, 0]) # if the key was not found, add it with 0 value
```

A better approach would be to use a dictionary to speed-up lookups, and a list comprehension for even faster processing:

```
d = dict(x)
y = [[k, d[k]] if k in d else [k, 0] for k in b]
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
print y
=> [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 0], ['d', 5]]
```

Comment: Down voter: care to comment? my answer gives the expected result!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But, I think a good answer here would be to help the OP understand that based on what they are trying to do, this is not anywhere close to the best approach to do this. It is fairly clear they are trying to perform operations based on the key in list x existing in b. So why not help provide an explanation to help the OP learn a few things about properly checking: aka `if key in b`? Also, the downvote came way before you added those comments in the code.

Comment: "way before" , yeah, like 50 seconds before. I was still editing the question when it was down voted, with no explanation

Comment: Enough to get the downvote. I'm just giving my input. You don't have to take it out on me. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#setup an eampty dict with all the required keys
y = {e:0 for e in b}
#populate elements of y using elements from x
y.update(x)
#convert the dict to a list in the required format.
y = [[k,v] for k,v in y.items()]

Out[133]: [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 0], ['d', 5]]
```

Comment: OP expects a _list_ as output, not a dict

Comment: Copied the intermediate output and have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One obviously wrong statement is

```
if sublist[0] == key:
    y.append(sublist)
else
    y.append([key,0])
```

This way you insert a pair of `[key, 0]` for every element of `x` that has a different key.

But you should consider rewriting your algorithm slightly. For instance, if `x` is a `dict` rather that associative list, you don't have to iterate through it to test for a key.

Answer (score 0):

I did some code here (needs improvement):

```
x = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['d', 5]]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
y = []


def find(my_list, letter):
    ''' if 'letter' is in 'x', returns [letter, value]. Otherwise, creates the list [letter, 0] '''
    for k, v in my_list:
        if letter == k:
            return [k, v]

    return [letter, 0]


for letter in b:
    y.append(
        find(x, letter)
    )

print y   # prints the result you want
```